# Probability with pulling four cards

Tags: probability

I thought this question wouldn't be hard, but my answer key says I'm wrong :(

So here's the question: What's the probability of getting at least one king -- in a standard 52-card deck -- if Jan pulls 4 random cards from it.

So I thought like this: 4/52 + 4/51 + 4/50 + 4/49 = 31.69%, but my the answer key says it's 28% ?

Did I do completely wrong or have I just missed a detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Try the converse probability: $P(X \geq 1)=1-P(X=0)$.

And you have to multiply the probabilities for every single pull:

$1-P(X=0)=1-48/52*47/51*\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to think of the complement, i.e. what is the probability of pulling no kings? Then, you want to pull four cards out of $48$ non-king cards. So, the probability of pulling no kings is
$$\frac{\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{4}},$$
and so, your desired probability is
$$1 - \frac{\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{4}}.$$

What you wrote down, $\frac{4}{52} + \frac{4}{51} + \frac{4}{50} + \frac{4}{49}$, has no particular mathematical meaning I can think of.